# Dynamically resizing table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a table where someone can enter a width and height, and it will be rezied to x units ov 16x16 td's

I have gotten it to work mostly properly, problems only arise when I am increasing the size on the x axis.

```
(function() {

var src = $('#grid-source');
var wrap = $('<div id="grid-overlay"></div>');
var gsize = 16;

var cols = 32;
var rows = 32;

// create overlay
var tbl = $('<table></table>');
for (var y = 1; y <= rows; y++) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var x = 1; x <= cols; x++) {
        var td = $('<td></td>');
        td.css('width', gsize+'px').css('height', gsize+'px');
        td.addClass('eraser');
        tr.append(td);
    }
    tbl.append(tr);
}
src.css('width', cols * gsize+'px').css('height', rows * gsize+'px')

// attach overlay
wrap.append(tbl);
src.after(wrap);

function setSize(newx, newy) {
    var xchange = newx - cols;
    var ychange = newy - rows;
    if (xchange < 0) {
        console.log('reducing x: ' + xchange);
        for (var x = xchange; x < 0; x++) {
            console.log(x);
            $('#grid-overlay table tbody tr').find('th:last, td:last').remove();
        }
    }
    if (ychange < 0) {
        console.log('reducing y: ' + ychange);
        for (var y = ychange; y < 0; y++) {
            $('#grid-overlay table tbody').find('tr:last').remove();
        }
    }
    if (xchange > 0) {
        console.log('increasing x: ' + xchange);
        $('#grid-overlay').find('tr').each(function(){
            $(this).find('td').eq(-1).after(Array(xchange).join("<td class='eraser' style='width:16px; height:16px;'></td>"));
        });
    }
    if (ychange > 0) {
        console.log('increasing y: ' + ychange);
        for (var y = 1; y <= ychange; y++) {
            var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
            for (var x = 1; x <= newx; x++) {
                var td = $('<td></td>');
                td.css('width', gsize+'px').css('height', gsize+'px');
                td.addClass('eraser');
                tr.append(td);
            }
            tbl.append(tr);
        }
    }

    cols = newx;
    rows = newy;
    src.css('width', cols * gsize+'px').css('height', rows * gsize+'px');
}

$('#resizeChart').click(function() {
    x  = $('#inputWidth').val();
    y  = $('#inputHeight').val();
    setSize(x,y);
});

})();
```

You can find a fully functional example here http://jsfiddle.net/6Ru72/

the questionable block of code is

```
    if (xchange > 0) {
        console.log('increasing x: ' + xchange);
        $('#grid-overlay').find('tr').each(function(){
            $(this).find('td').eq(-1).after(Array(xchange).join("<td class='eraser' style='width:16px; height:16px;'></td>"));
        });
    }
```

if you tinker with the demo, you will see it only increases the width of the table after a certain point along the y axis. Does anyone have an idea why this behavior is happening?
image of the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFH3I.png

Comment: Do you mean how the table tries to fit to the width of the window if you set it to wider than the width?

Comment: Here is an image example of my problem. http://i.imgur.com/2AoSBsL.png for this image I set it down to 5x5, then increased it to 10x10, then when expanding again to 15x15, you get this. http://i.imgur.com/h3d750v.png

Comment: does adding 1 to xchange solve your problem? like `$(this).find('td').eq(-1).after(Array(xchange + 1).join("<td class='eraser' style='width:16px; height:16px;'></td>"));
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in

```
$(this).find('td').eq(-1).after(Array(xchange).join("<td class='eraser' style='width:16px; height:16px;'></td>")); });
```

to get the right number of repeats, you have to increase `xchange` value by one:

```
$(this).find('td').eq(-1).after(Array(xchange + 1).join("<td class='eraser' style='width:16px; height:16px;'></td>")); });
```

the `join()` function joins the elements of an ( in this case empty ) array with the string of your choice, in this case html markup for your table data. thus if you want to get the right number of repeats, you have to increase the number by one.

I did some changes to your code ( I basically written it all from the scratch, sorry, but feel free to use it if you feel like it ).

```
(function() {

    String.prototype.repeat = function( num )
    {
        return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
    }

    var src = $('#grid-source');
    var wrap = $('<div id="grid-overlay"></div>');
    var gsize = 16;

    var td_html = '<td class="eraser" style="width:'+gsize+'px;height:'+gsize+'px"></td>';

    var cols = 32;
    var rows = 32;

    // create overlay
    var tbl = $('<table></table>');

    tbl.html(('<tr>' + td_html.repeat(cols) + '</tr>').repeat(rows));

    src.css('width', cols * gsize+'px').css('height', rows * gsize+'px')

    // attach overlay
    wrap.append(tbl);
    src.after(wrap);

    function setSize(x, y) {
        var x_total = parseInt(x);
        x = x - tbl.find('tr:first td').length;
        y = y - tbl.find('tr').length;

        if(x > 0){
            var html = td_html.repeat(x);
            tbl.find('tr').each(function(){
                $(this).append(html);
            });
        }

        if(x < 0)
            tbl.find('tr').each(function(){
                $(this).find('td').slice(x).remove();
            });

        if(y > 0)
            tbl.append(('<tr>' + td.html.repeat(x_total) + '</tr>').repeat(y));

        if(y < 0)
            tbl.find('tr').slice(y).remove();

        src.css({'width' : tbl.find('tr:first td').length * gsize+'px', 'height':  tbl.find('tr').length+'px'});
    }

    $('#resizeChart').click(function() {
        x  = $('#inputWidth').val();
        y  = $('#inputHeight').val();
        setSize(x,y);
    });

})();
```

This works well in case you need to keep the old `<td>` and `<tr>` elements ( because of some data stored in them, or whatever ). If you don't need to keep the old rows and data however, you can replace all the code in `setSize()` function with

```
tab.html(('<tr>' + ('<td class="eraser" style="width:'+gsize+'px;height:'+gsize+'px"></td>').repeat(parseInt(x))).repeat(parseInt(y)));
```

Comment: Looks good. I get some ideas from your rewrite. My version also allows you to keep the old data in the td and tr elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#resizeChart').click(function() {     
        var $oldTable = $('#table');   
        var $table = $('<table>').attr('id', 'table');        
        var width = $('#inputWidth').val();
        var height = $('#inputHeight').val();

        for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            var $tr = $('<tr>');            
            for (var column=0; column < width; column++) {
                var $td = $('<td>');
                $td.html(getCellValue($oldTable, row, column));
                $tr.append($td);
            }            
            $table.append($tr);               
        }
        $oldTable.remove();
        $('#grid-source').append($table);
    });
})();

function getCellValue($table, row, col) {
    var $trs = $table.find('tr');
    return $trs.length >= row && $($trs[row]).find('td').length >= col
        ? $($($trs[row]).find('td')[col]).html() : '';
}
```

Here is working

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ru72/10/)

Comment: This is good code, but doesnt allow me to retain any data in the tr's or td's. Also, why do you use $ for your variables?

Comment: I've updated my answer to retain old values, hope this will help. For your second question, I use it as naming convention to all jQuery variables.